# jenkins variable email notification subject

Tags: variables, jenkins

I have a jenkins jobs and running Build goals: test -PAllPackages -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true -Denvironment=L2.

I want the -Denvironment=L2 value to appear in the editable email notification Default Subject. Can anybody help me with this?